# Where Criteria on empty field

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, postgresql-9.3

Consider I have a table Plan with following values.

```
planName(VARCHAR2) | validFrom(timestamp) | validTo(timestamp)
---------------------------------------------------------------
planA              |         20-10-2013   |
```

What select query should I write with a where criteria on 'validTo' field so that to obtain that row even if the value is empty in 'validTo'

for Example, if I write the query like :-

```
select * 
from plan 
where validFrom > to_Date('20-10-2013', 'DD-MM,YYYY') 
  and validTo < to_Date('31-12-2029', 'DD-MM,YYYY')
```

and obtaining result like

```
planName(VARCHAR2) | validFrom(timestamp) | validTo(timestamp)
---------------------------------------------------------------
                   |                      |
```

but I need to fetch that row also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks every one I got the approach, hope this will support others too.

```
select * from plan where COALESCE(validFrom , to_date('12/10/2799', 'DD/MM/YYYY')) > to_Date('20/10/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND COALESCE(validFrom , to_date('1/01/1700', 'DD/MM/YYYY'))< to_Date('31/12/2029', 'DD/MM/YYYY');
```

If the value is null COALESCE() will compare with the next not null value.

COALESCE is an alternate approach to NVL.

Answer (score 1):

This will work,

```
select * 
from plan 
where 
validFrom > to_Date('20-10-2013', 'DD-MM,YYYY') 
  and 
(validTo < to_Date('31-12-2029', 'DD-MM,YYYY') or validTo is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add `ValidTo IS NULL` in the WHERE clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM plan 
WHERE (validFrom > to_Date('20-10-2013', 'DD-MM,YYYY')) 
      AND (validTo < to_Date('31-12-2029', 'DD-MM,YYYY') OR validTo IS NULL)
```

Comment: Is there any operations like NVL can be used in this situation?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to specify all column names to use the NVL function on the ValidTo Column

Comment: Null scenario is only for 'Validto' ,so you need to group only 'validto' date check and null check.Like validFrom > to_Date('20-10-2013', 'DD-MM,YYYY') 
  and 
(validTo < to_Date('31-12-2029', 'DD-MM,YYYY') or validTo is null)

Comment: Consider if i have multiple date fields, i need to provide is null for all fields right??? Is there any other generic approach for the same.